# Filtered arrays and since() functionality in ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a backend resource that contains *user activities* and in the application I would like to present activities based on a single day's worth of activities. I have an `ArrayController` called **ActivitiesController** defined in the router like this:

```
this.resource('activities', { path: '/activities/:by_date' }, function() {
    this.route('new');
});
```

The REST API provides the following GET method:

```
GET /activities/[by_date]
```

So far this looks pretty symmetrical and achievable but I'm running into two problems:

1. **Parameterized array find**. Typically a parameterized route would be serviced by a `ObjectController` but in this case the `by_date` parameter simply reduces/filters the array of activities but it's still an array that's returned. I'm not sure how to structure this in the model hook in the `ActivitiesRoute` so that its effectively doing a "findAll" rather than expecting a singular resultset.
2. **Since functionality**. As there is a reasonable network cost in bringing back these arrays of activities I would like to minimize this as much as possible and the REST API supports this by allowing for a `since` parameter to be passed along with the date of the last request. This way the server simply responds with a `304` code if no records have been updated since the last call and if there are new records only the *new* records are returned. Is there anyway to get this "out of the box" with ember-data? Does this require building a custom Adaptor? If so, are there any open source solutions that are available?

p.s. I was thinking that part of the answer to #2 might be to incorporate Alex Speller's *Query Parameters*: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/query-string-support-in-ember-router/1962/48

Comment: looking in more detail at the *Query Parameters* I'm less convinced it will solve my "since" problem because it seems to have strong ties to the URL which I actually do *not* want in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your route's model hook look like? I am thinking something like this should work:

```
model: function(params) {
  return this.store.find('activity', { by_date: params.by_date });
}
```

Comment: Well this wouldn't address the **since functionality**. As for the **parameterized array find** ... yes I guess in a way it does but what I don't like is that it *always* goes back to the server to retrieve the data. I supposed I could build some logic around that to have it behave better by caching the returned Ids to SessionStorage. Let me ponder this over a little and I'll reply back here tomorrow. Thanks for pushing back to this solution as I'd jumped past it maybe too quickly.

Comment: @ken well, you can manually add a since parameter obviously, but that's not "out of the box". It looks like EmberData does have a sinceToken that is passed to the server as `since`, but I am not exactly sure how to use it.

Comment: very interesting WRT to the `since` parameter ... I'm wondering if I should ask about this on the Discourse discussion thread or as a SO question.